# SQL Server always running

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a personal computer where I have different instances of SQL server running (developer edition) with both integration services and analysis services (one in tabular and one in multidimensional). I use it for practice and to improve my skills. The start mode in Configuration Manager is "Automatic". So I have two instances each with both SSIS and SSAS. When I am not using SQL Server will these services use a lot of resources on my computer by simply running in the background?

Thanks

Comment: You can put the mode to manual and start only when you are working. Why to keep it as automatic since its not database server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server takes up as much memory as it needs.
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/
https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/max-memory/

I also have it on a laptop, but I have the services set to manual.  They're only consuming memory when I need them to.

**DataOnWheels** has a great post about starting/stopping SQL Server Services with Powershell.
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/starting-and-stopping-sql-server-with-powershell

*Edited after I Implemented it on my laptop, and changed name of Service since most users I know have "MSSQLSERVER" as the service name:

To Start SQL Server

```
##Needs to run in admin Mode. 

##Ensure permissions are valid
SET-EXECUTIONPOLICY RemoteSigned

##To Start SQL Server Automatically
SET-Service 'MSSQLSERVER' -StartupType MANUAL
START-Service -NAME 'MSSQLSERVER'
```

To Stop SQL Server:

```
##Needs to run in admin Mode. 

##Ensure permissions are valid
SET-EXECUTIONPOLICY RemoteSigned

##To Stop SQL Server 
SET-Service 'MSSQLSERVER' -StartupType Disabled
STOP-Service -NAME 'MSSQLSERVER' -FORCE
```

I'd suggest running those through a BAT file and linking that to an icon on your desktop.

I suggest it because it's what I'm about to do.

Answer (score 3):

As usual in these cases, "It depends".

Depends, as a minumum, on:

1. How performant is your PC in general (especially: how much RAM, how many CPUs, are your disks SSD, etc).
2. How often do you practice with SQL Server.

Personally, I have a situation like yours and I don't feel any kind of slowness. Starting/stopping services can be boring when you are in a hurry, but if there are situations in which you need "all the power" of your PC, you can safely stop or pause SQL Server related services: it is not a DB server, then you know when you can stop it.

An idea could be to make a script to stop/start all SQL related services.

Comment: Thanks, both answers are good but I choose to accept the other one.